# Display image in canvas with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to click on a button on my page and load an image into a canvas at some X,Y coordinates?

The following code is what I have below. I would like the image to be in either image/photo.jpg or in the same directory but preferably in a subdirectory of the main page.

**Question: How to make a JPG show up in a canvas with the click of a button on the web page?

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>
    function draw(){  
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");  
        var img = new Image():  
      //  img.src = "2c.jpg";  
        img.src = "/images/2c.jpg";  

        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);  
    }


</script>


<body background="Black">

<div align="center">
    <button type="button" onclick="draw()">Show Image on Canvas</button> 

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="900" height="400" style="border:2px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
</div>

<script>
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.font="20px Arial";

    ctx.fillText("Royal Flush     $",500,50);
    ctx.fillText("Striaght Flush  $",500,80);
    ctx.fillText("Flush           $",500,110);
    ctx.fillText("Four of a Kind  $",500,140);
    ctx.fillText("Full House      $",500,170);
    ctx.fillText("Three of a Kind $",500,200);
    ctx.fillText("Two Pair        $",500,230);
    ctx.fillText("Pair of ACES    $",500,260);


    ctx.rect(495,10,270,350);
    ctx.stroke();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

March 6th, 2014 Code:

How is the following code not working. Do you have to have an ID tag on Canvas. The page will display but for some reason the image will not when the button is clicked. The image is in the same directory that my index.html file is in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
    canvas{
       border: 5px solid black;
    }
</style>

</html>
    <button id="galaxy">Add image #1</button>
    <button id="circles">Add image #2</button><span></span>
    <canvas width="500" height="500"></canvas>

<script>
  var Images = {};

function loadImages(list){
    var total = 0;
    document.querySelector("span").innerText = "...Loading...";
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        var img = new Image();
        Images[list[i].name] = img;
        img.onload = function(){
            total++;
            if(total == list.length){
                document.querySelector("span").innerText = "...Loaded.";
            }
        };
        img.src = list[i].url;
    }
}

function drawImage(img){
    var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(Images[img], 0, 0, 50, 50);
}

loadImages([{
    name: "2c.jpg",
    url: "mp.jpg"
},{
    name: "mp.jpg",
    url: "mp.jpg"
}]);

document.querySelector("#galaxy").addEventListener("click", function(){
    drawImage("galaxy");
});

document.querySelector("#circles").addEventListener("click", function(){
    drawImage("weirdCircles");
});

</script>   

</html>
```

Comment: `var img = new Image:` <- `;`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wait till the image is loaded before drawing:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){        /*or*/  img.addEventListener("load", function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);                 ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
};                                      };
img.src = "/images/2c.jpg";
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/YcLgw/

---

### If you have more than one image in your game,

It is better to preload all images before it starts.

Preload images: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/uCQAH/ (Without jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Lr9Gb/)

---

If you are more familiar with [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming): http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/2F2gu/

```
function ImageCollection(list, callback){
    var total = 0, images = {};   //private :)
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        var img = new Image();
        images[list[i].name] = img;
        img.onload = function(){
            total++;
            if(total == list.length){
                callback && callback();
            }
        };
        img.src = list[i].url;
    }
    this.get = function(name){
        return images[name] || (function(){throw "Not exist"})();
    };
}

//Create an ImageCollection to load and store my images
var images = new ImageCollection([{
    name: "MyImage", url: "//example.com/example.jpg"
}]);

//To pick and draw an image from the collection:
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(images.get("MyImage"), 0, 0);
```

Comment: Does the image img.src come first or does the onload come first because how does it draw since the img.src is after the img.onload. I am not seeing it here.

Comment: Just tried it and it does not work either. I will past the new code or that script part above.

Comment: @user3376708 - `onload` should be first because your image will be start loading as soon as you set the `src`.

Comment: @user3376708 - Why are you setting the `src` twice?

Comment: I am new to javascript and that seems cock-eyes to me. So when you have the img.src you have to have an img.onload = function directly above. This is what I am not certain of but it did not work either way.

Comment: @user3376708 - Basically yes. You always have to wait until the image is loaded before drawing it. Take a look at the demo in my answer.

Comment: How long does it take to load, because nothing after 1 minutes or so. is there a really fast way to make the code load. I am going to make a poker game and need the cards to flip fast just like in the vegas coin op games.

Comment: @user3376708 - If you are making a game, then you should have preloaded all the resources first. (That's what the loading screens in online games are for) Nonetheless, images shouldn't take a minute to load.

Comment: @user3376708 - This is one way of preloading images: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/uCQAH/

Comment: I have still not getting it to work.  loadImages([{
        name: "2c.jpg",
        url: "2c.jpg"
    }]);   When you call this code what is with the [] around the parameters and the list can that be any number of items or an array.

Comment: @user3376708 - My code uses jQuery for easy element-selecting purposes. If you do not have jQuery included you must modify all `$` to native methods or remove unnecessary debugging lines like `$().text`: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Lr9Gb/

Comment: @user3376708 - And remember to wrap your code with `onload` so that the elements exist when attaching listeners.

Comment: It tried your new example that you had listed and nothing. The page does come up with the button and the canvas is there but nothing happens when I click a button. I will post above.

Comment: @user3376708 - It doesn't work is because you didn't wrap your entire code with `onload` or putting it at the end of `body`. You have to wait for the page to finish loading before doing anything

Comment: I moved it to the bottom and still do not see an image but on a couple of times I did see the loaded line of text.

Comment: @user3376708 - I see the problem. The function I made lets you name your images so that you can use it later in the future. In your code you are still using the names in my demo: `drawImage("galaxy");`. You should change it to the names you defined: `2c.jpg` and `mp.jpg`.

Comment: How does JSFiddle do the magic? The HTML neither references the JS nor the CSS and yet it works. What do I need to do to make it work on my machine without JSFiddle?

Comment: @ThomasWeller JSFiddle automatically generates the full HTML with the JS and CSS inserted. Right click on the Result area and click "View frame source" to see the actual HTML.